# drop discrete columns pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How would I automatically drop columns with too few discrete step? There is an unknown number of steps, but a good start would be to drop columns with less than 100 discrete possible values.

This might involve calculating the number of unique values within a column and dropping those will less than 100. Something like, but more elegant.

```
for column in X.columns:
   if len(X[column].unique()) < 100:
      del X[column]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with comparing by [`DataFrame.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html) by 'inverted' condition - `< 100` to `>=100` for select columns by `>=100` mask:

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                   'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'F':list('aaabbb')})

print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  a  4  7  1  5  a
1  b  5  8  3  3  a
2  c  4  9  5  6  a
3  d  5  4  7  9  b
4  e  5  2  1  2  b
5  f  4  3  0  4  b

df = df.loc[:, df.nunique() >= 4]
print (df)
   A  C  D  E
0  a  7  1  5
1  b  8  3  3
2  c  9  5  6
3  d  4  7  9
4  e  2  1  2
5  f  3  0  4
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.nunique())
A    6
B    2
C    6
D    5
E    6
F    2
dtype: int64
```